# Two-way ANOVA robustness against normality violations

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I recently read the article "[Is It Really Robust?](http://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=de&user=TeaZX90AAAAJ&citation_for_view=TeaZX90AAAAJ%3ad1gkVwhDpl0C)" (Schmider, E., Ziegler M., Danay, E., Beyer, L. & Bühner M., 2010) 
The authors of the article come to the conclusion that an ANOVA is quite robust against violations of the normality assumption.

However the study focusses on one-way ANOVAs. I would like to know if these findings can be generalized on a two-way repeated measures ANOVA?

References to peer-reviewed articles are highly appreciated!

---

#### References

Schmider, E., Ziegler M., Danay, E., Beyer, L. & Bühner M. (2010). Is It Really Robust?.*Methodology, 6 (4),* 147 - 151.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the methodology used by the Schmidler et al paper is seriously flawed*, so their results are questionable even for the one-way, fixed-effect design they studied.

*Specifically, to simulate Type I or Type II error using a Monte Carlo simulation, one needs to use *all* samples that were generated by the Monte Carlo process. Just using the 10% selected by some nonrandom selection method does not give a simulation of the sampling distribution for the test statistic; however, it is this sampling distribution that needs to be simulated.

Comment: The 10% of samples they've picked are the ones that most resemble the population distribution, meaning that the samples were definitely non-normal (in the non-normal conditions, of course)--which is what they're trying to get to (and which is why they've done this). I see your point, but I think saying their methodology is "seriously flawed" might be something of an overstatement.

Comment: @Patrick I guess "seriously flawed" is a judgment call which may vary from individual to individual. Possibly my brief explanation was too brief, so here's a little more: In the process of their selection of the 10% of samples, they used 24 X 50,000 hypothesis tests. That presents a huge multiple testing problem that they did not even mention. I see that in itself as casting serious doubt on the credibility of the results.